# building set of 2D orthogonal polynomials with minimum crossed terms

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I am working with 2D orthogonal polynomials. They are function of (x,y) and are gradient-orthogonal on the unit square:

$$
<P(x,y),Q(x,y)> = \int_{-1}^{+1}\int_{-1}^{+1}(\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y})dxdy
$$
Using the Gram-Schmidt procedure I have arrived at a set of orthogonal polynomials ordered with increasing power, ie:
$$
P_{10} = \frac{x}{2}\\
P_{11} = \frac{y}{2}\\
P_{20} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}x^2\\
P_{21} = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}xy\\
P_{22} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}y^2\\
$$
etc. For power 4 or higher, it is not possible to find polynomials that only contain one monomial of the highest power. For instance I get:
$$
P_{52} = K(x^3y^2+lower powers)\\
P_{54} = K'(xy^4 +ax^3y ^2+lowerpowers)\\
$$
with a<<1. I would like to transform the polynomial set to minimize this "mixing" so that the polynomials reflect better my system symmetries. When only 2 polynomials are combined like above it is easy to modify them with a orthogonal transformation (rotation) so that the coefficients of the unwanted monomials become minimum: I need to find only one angle. When 3 polynomials are combined then it is a hassle because I must find 3 angles:
$$
P_{72} = K(x^5y^2+lower powers)\\
P_{74} = K'(x^3y^4 +ax^5y^2+lowerpowers)\\
P_{76} = K''(xy^6 + bx^3y^4 +cx^5y^2+lowerpowers)\\
$$
I would like to find a way to transform such polynomials when there is up to 5 mixed terms. Is there a standard procedure to do it ? Any suggestion or idea to reformulate this problem in a more convenient way ? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The inner product that you use is not a good one, because $\| P \| = 0$ means $\| \nabla P \| = 0$, which in turn does *not* mean $P = 0$, as it should. Are you maybe working only with those polynomials that are $0$ in $(0,0)$?

Comment: That's a good point. Since the inner product is only based on derivatives, the constant terms in the polynomials are irrelevant. So I think the inner product should be defined on a subspace that excludes constant monomials: "polynomials" then refers to linear combination of monomials of power >= 1 (x, y, x^2, xy, y^2, etc)